# Bash: get result from 1 loop independent from 2

Tags: bash, loops, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have some question about using loops in the bash script. I need to send multiple POST request with different values. So I used the loops.
In 1 loops I change the name of profile just add to it the number from 1 to 500

```
#!/bin/bash
token="Authorization: Bearer h-bCxY3nCJD_Oro_aQE15soo-XFewv1bzsArbd46iJrH1t5Fxa3TLYaQ3Q"
url="http://ad44fcfa01aad11e98c201.amazonaws.com/api/v0.1/scanprofiles"
q=500

name=3_Ubuntu_internal

for ((i = 0; i < q; i++))
 do
    data='{"target":{"scan_type":"internal","ip_range":"10.142.0.2-10.142.0.5","ports":"1042"},"name":"'$name$i'","run_immediately":"False"}'
    echo "${data}"
    curl -X POST $url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "$token" -d "$data"
 done
```

And it works, creates 500 profile with default parameters of IP and ports. But then I need to change default ports from 1042 to one from the array from 1042 to 1237. I try to create another one loop inside of existing but get not exactly that results what I want. A.e. for each from 500 profiles applying firstly 1042 port, then 1043 and so on. And I want to create profile 1 with 1042 port, profile 2 - 1043 and so on. Of course the number of profiles more the number of ports from 1042 to 1237 but it's OK, ports can be repeated again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Add a variable for the start port:

```
port=1042
```

and increment it inside the loop:

```
for ((i = 0; i < q; i++))
 do
    data='{"target":{"scan_type":"internal","ip_range":"10.142.0.2-10.142.0.5","ports":"'${port}'"},"name":"'$name$i'","run_immediately":"False"}'
    echo "${data}"
    curl -X POST $url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "$token" -d "$data"
    port=$((port+1))
 done
```

This way every next port will be an increment of the previous one.

If you can not go over port 1237 (for example) you can add inside the loop just after the port=$((port+1)) the following if:

```
if [ "${port}" -eq "1237" ];then
    port=1042
fi
```

... which will reset the counter and start the port increment from 1042 again.